# how to create webhooks programatically in slack . Or if there is any easy and efficient way to do it

Tags: php, webhooks, slack

How to create webhooks programatically . Or   is their any easy and efficient 
 way to create webhooks programatically in slack to send message

Comment: Welcome StackOverflow website! First, you should understand a single thing: your question is not about a direct problem in a code, but rather a request for us to google for you. Post what you have tried and done already, break the problem into smaller ones, and then we're eager to help!

Comment: Also, you should really pay attention to the language you are writing in. If it is poorly written, most people will just downvote and go on. No one likes reading and answering a question in which the TC did not want to put a little bit of his own time to write correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create web hooks programmatically in Slack.